# Report elements on left getting pushed down when tablix on the right side expands

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I have a report with a tablix on the right side and several textboxes arranged in rows and columns on the left. While previewing the report, the tablix gets expanded with the separate values in them and because of which some of the text boxes are also getting pushed down leaving blanks spaces and making the report look unformatted.

I have attached the report format.  Please let me know if you have any solution to this issue.

[image: report format]

Answer (score 5):

You need to place your report items in rectangles to stop them interacting with each other.  Put your items on the left all into the same one and the table on the right into it's own.

Comment: Tried this multiple times. When I put all the left elements into one rectangle and right side tablix into another one, I can still see blank spaces all around and also now the tablix also got pushed down leaving a huge blank space at the top.

Comment: @SSASdeveloper  Please add some screenshots of your design view to your question.  I guarantee you rectangles are how you fix this.

Comment: Thanks iamdave for the response. I have added links to the images. I tried 1. keeping tablixes and textboxes in separate rectangles, 2. keep all textbox elements inside a rectangle and leave tablixes as it is, 3. keep all tablixes in one rectangle and leave text boxes as it is 4. Keep everything tablixes and textboxes inside a single rectangle. None of them worked. Probably i am missing something.

Comment: @SSASdeveloper  From your screenshot, it is clear you have not put everything on the left of the table into one rectangle.  Do this and you should be fine.  I think you can just leave the table on its own.

Comment: Sorry that my description wasn't clear. that screenshot is something I took to show the format, I have tried the following already using rectangles:  1. keeping all textboxes inside a single rectangle and leave tables as is, 2. keep textboxes in one rectangle and tables in other,3. keep all items in one single rectangle, 4. keep only tables inside rectangle and textboxes as is.. So far nothing worked for me

Comment: @SSASdeveloper Can you please post your various designs and what it looks like when previewed, as what you have posted looks like it should work.

Comment: @SSASdeveloper  Or alternatively if you are able, create a dummy query to return a data set similar to your report and upload the RDL somewhere I can download it.

Comment: rearranged the tables side by side on the top of the page, placed textboxes below the tables. That worked. Didn't use any rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Can Grow attribute to False or did you need it to expand? If so I would actually increase your Tablix size to the max it can to not push the text boxes and then set the property to Can Grow to false.

Comment: I need the tablix to expand when there is value for the attributes. What I am not getting is how to increase the size of the tablix without increasing the height of each cell in the tablix. I tried to increase the size of the tablix by specifying the size property then it's increasing the height of each cell in tablix.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why rectangles didn't work for you. I have a similar report I am trying to create with the same format. I had the same problem you mentioned where white space appeared above my report objects, and the objects on the left still did not appear in the correct places.

What I found was that you need to create the rectangle first and then add objects into it. It appears that the above problem occurs when you try to place a rectangle on top of your report objects.

I know this is 4 years late, but I thought this might hopefully save someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Report Properties to select columns number from 1 to 2 to see information side by side instead of going to next page.

Report Properties

[image: 1]

Comment: 2 columns seem to work although how do you add content to column 2 once settings are updated? It seems to be grayed out all the time and you cannot drag items into it.